# Mongoose error: nesting Schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question about nesting Mongoose schema.

Here is a simple code snippet

```
var aSchema = new Schema({bar: String});
var bSchema = new Schema({a: aSchema, foo: String});
var cSchema = new Schema({as: [aSchema], foo:String});
```

This will throw `TypeError` on `bSchema`: `TypeError: Undefined type at 's' Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.`, but works fine for `cSchema`.

Just want to ask why `bSchema` does not work. Cannot find explanation in Mongoose doc. Thanks.

Comment: Is the `a` property of `bSchema` supposed to be a reference to an `aSchema` object? Don't do that. Do: `a:{type: Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId', ref: 'a'}` where the `a` in `ref:a` is the name of the mongoose model that you create using `aSchema`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MongoDB is **not** a relational database. This can cause confusion for some who are used to the RDBS model (I still get tripped up occasionally...but I'm really not a DB guy).

Oftentimes, you'll find it beneficial to reference other *documents* in your Mongo entities. Mongoose schemas provide a very simple and effective way to do this that feels very relational.

When defining a schema that will store a reference to a different type of document, you define the relevant property as an object with a `type` and a `ref`. Typically when defining schema properties, you can simply say: `a: Number`; however, Mongoose provides many different options for a schema property other than type:

```
a: {
   type: Number,
   required: true   
}
```

Setting `required: true` will prevent us from saving a document where the `a` property is not present.

Once you understand how to define your schemas with object definitions, you can leverage Mongoose's population mechanic:

```
a: {
   type: Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: 'a'
}
```

This tells Mongoose to store the `ObjectId` (a Mongoose-specific identifier) of a specific `a` document as the `a` property of our schema. Still following me?

When setting this property on a Mongoose document, you can simply say: `doc.a = myA`. When you go to save `doc`, Mongoose will automagically make the conversion and only store the ID in your database.

When retrieving a document that references another schema, you'll need to populate. I won't go into that, but its pretty simple - [check out the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue as I was completely new to the **MongoDB**. Later I found we need to use the relationship as below with the help of **Mongoose**.

Below is my country schema.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var CountrySchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    activeStatus: Boolean,
    createdOn: Date,
    updatedOn: Date
});
```

And I can use this schema in my State schema as follows.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var StateSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    country: {type: ObjectId, ref: "Country"},
    activeStatus: Boolean,
    createdOn: Date,
    updatedOn: Date
});
```

Here I am using pointing to my other schema with the help of **ref**.